# Which configuration file client is using to connect to hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

When the edge node had multiple hadoop distributions, there can be multiple configuration files scattered across the  directories.

In those cases, how to know which configuration file the client is referring to, for it to connect to the cluster. ( say, for Yarn ). One option is to look at .**bashrc** file to find out if the **HADOOP_HOME** variable is set.

Are there are any other options to find this out . ( obviously, using the find command to search for a file will not solve the purpose ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop provides `classpath` command. Read the description of the command below:

```
classpath        prints the class path needed to get the
                 Hadoop jar and the required libraries
```

You can execute this command as:

```
hadoop classpath
```

or

```
yarn classpath
```

Both these commands, should give you almost identical results. 
For e.g. I got following output, for `hadoop classpath`

```
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\bin>hadoop classpath
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\etc\hadoop;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\common\*;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\hdfs;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\yarn\*;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*;
e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*;
e:\hdp\tez-0.7.0.2.3.0.0-2557\conf\;
e:\hdp\tez-0.7.0.2.3.0.0-2557\*;
e:\hdp\tez-0.7.0.2.3.0.0-2557\lib\*;
```

All these paths contain **HADOOP_HOME** as the parent path. In my case, it is: "e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557". From this path, you can easily figure out, which distribution of Hadoop, is your client referring to.

In my case, my client is using the Hadoop configurations and jars from: "e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557" directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can run env command to get HADOOP_HOME for the session. Even if you overwrite HADOOP_HOME, env will give current value of the session.

Comment: @Thanks Durga. it seems env command is not showing hadoop_home.